# POST form Login using PHP cURL

Tags: php, curl

I can't login to a website throughout the terminal using my PHP and cURL code, can someone explain where I am failing?

```
<?php
    $URL = 'https://example.com/login.cgi';
    $agent = 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.12; rv:50.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/50.0';

    $ch = curl_init();  
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,$URL);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 30); 
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, array(
                'username' => 'USER',
                'password' => 'PASS'));
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPAUTH, CURLAUTH_ANY);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded'));
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, $agent);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
    $status_code = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);   //get status code

    $result = curl_exec ($ch);
    curl_close ($ch);
    echo $result;
?>
```

The form is this:

```
<form name="frmLogin" action="login.cgi" method="POST" onsubmit="return Login(1)">
       <input type="hidden" name="tz_offset">
                <input type="text" name="username" size="20">
                <input type="password" name="password" size="20">
                <input type="submit" value="Entra" name="btnSubmit">
</form>
```

Comment: curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, array(
                'username' => 'USER',
                'password' => 'PASS'));

Is the username/password required as HTTP authentication to a password protected directory?

Comment: Well, how should we know what that server does to come to the conclusion that you are not authorized? Are we meant to _guess_ that servers internal logic?

Comment: @BizWedsCode The form shown in the question says that the credentials are expected as POST fields.

Comment: Is the website you are trying to log into controlled by you? If not, you need to show us the login form as it appears on that website (get the page source in Chrome, for example). You may be missing another field required in the login form as set by the other website.

Comment: Logging into a website almost always involves creating a session, which requires you to save the cookies received and send them on future requests. You have no code to do this.